# How to end program while loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running into an issue with the following python 3.x code in which the `while(keepAlive):` continues, even after `keepAlive` is false. When the user enters "1", `Killing Program...` is displayed but while loop continues. I'm familiar with other languages, but just starting out with python. It seems like I must have made a simple mistake... I'd appreciate it if someone could point it out.

```
keepAlive = True

def main():
    if(input("Enter 1 to end program") == "1"):
        print("Killing program...")
        keepAlive = False

while(keepAlive):
    main()
```

Thanks

Comment: [Variable scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error)

Comment: The `keepAlive` *inside* `main` is unrelated to the one outside. Read up on Python's scoping http://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the module keepAlive and the local keepAlive within main are two independent names.  To tie them together, declare keepAlive within main to be global.  The following works.

```
keepAlive = True

def main():
    global keepAlive
    if(input("Enter 1 to end program") == "1"):
        print("Killing program...")
        keepAlive = False

while(keepAlive):
    main()
```

Look up 'global' in the Python doc index and you should find an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As variable scoping had been mentioned, try putting the `if` statement in  the while loop  and declaring keepAlive   before the `while`.